# Getting the proper type inference and editor suggestions at the same time

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function that takes a config object and returns it's processed version, which has same keys, but different values. This function must:

1. Provide the suggestions of config's properties when I want to call the function.
2. Let the compiler know what properties exactly are returned from the function.

.

```
type Config = {
    a?: number
    b?: string
}

function f(x: Config): Config {
    return x
}

function g<T extends Config>(x: T): T {
    return x
}
```

In this code **f()** satisfies only the first requirement, and **g()** satisfies only the second:

```
f({a: 1}).<CTRL+SPACE> // Shows that the result's type is "{ a?: number, b?: string }", but I want it to be "{ a: number }".

g({<CTRL+SPACE> // Doesn't show suggestions for Config type.
```

Is there a way to write a function that satisfies both of the requirements?

Comment: I think it's not about the language specifically, but about some tool you're using for completion. And that tool is missing from the question.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz most tools use the typescript language service built into the compiler so it should work in the same way mostly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an intersection type between `T` and `Config` will actually help code completion get the suggestions right and it won't impact type inference, as far as I can tell:

```
type Config = {
    a?: number
    b?: string
}

function g<T extends Config>(x: T & Config): T {
    return x
}
let justA = g({ a: 0 });// of type { a: number }
g ({ /* Ctrl Space here suggets a and b  */})
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Config%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20g%3CT%20extends%20Config%3E(x%3A%20T%20%26%20Config)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20x%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20justA%20%3D%20g(%7B%20a%3A%200%20%7D)%3B%2F%2F%20of%20type%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Ag%20(%7B%20%2F*%20Ctrl%20Space%20here%20suggets%20a%20and%20b%20%20*%2F%7D))

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify the object in the function, and remove the return type from the signature.

In your example, you have to modify the object -- creating a new object with the same values as you want (Object.assign should work) -- because if you're returning the object that went into it, that same type will be returned (the compiler accepted a certain type, even if some optional properties are null).

Removing the return type from the signature should allow type inference to work and infer a new type. You might have to have a custom  type defined. If not, you might get 'any', and have to check for the properties you want later. I say "might" because I'm not sure about the version of TypeScript and its settings on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your case. But if you are changing types of function argument and you know what data types will your function return based on incoming type (let say every property which has type of string will produce number and every other type will produce string), then you can use mapped type like this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Config%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MappedType%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20string%20%3F%20number%20%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20g%3CT%20extends%20Config%3E(x%3A%20T)%3A%20MappedType%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20justA%20%3D%20g(%7B%20a%3A%200%2C%20b%3A%20%22%22%2C%20c%3A%205%20%7D)%3B%0D%0AjustA.%2F%2F%20of%20type%20ConfigLike%20with%20different%20types%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20g(%7B%2F*%20suggestions%20work%20as%20well%20%20*%2F%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

For more info: [Advanced types docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)